# Spring MVC: correct configuration for WebMvcConfigurerAdapter with HttpMessageConverters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

Working with Spring Framework `4.3.6`

About MVC, declaring:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
```

with:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
   converters.add(httpMessageConverterConfig.stringHttpMessageConverter());
   converters.add(httpMessageConverterConfig.mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter());
   converters.add(httpMessageConverterConfig.mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
}
```

Thus:

1. String
2. XML
3. Json

For some `@Test` methods fail

Where working with:

```
resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get(uri).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                    .andDo(print());
```

And thanks to: `.andDo(print());` I can see the following:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /personas
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Accept=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}

Handler:
             Type = ....
           Method = public com.manuel....

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = <collection>
  <item>
    <id>087</id>
    <nombre>Leonardo</nombre>
    <apellido>Jordan</apellido>
  </item>
  ....
</collection>
```

Observe:

- For `MockHttpServletRequest` and `MockHttpServletRequest` the headers are correct. Both related with `JSON`
- For `MockHttpServletRequest` even when the headers are related with `JSON`, observe that the body is in `XML`.

Thus the error message is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "collection", exception: Property ['collection'] not found in path $
    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:245)
```

If the client is `RestTemplate`

Defined or created through:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new MockMvcClientHttpRequestFactory(mockMvc));
```

with:

```
requestEntity = RequestEntity.get(uri).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                                                      .build();
```

the error is:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@5874adee; line: 1, column: 2]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@5874adee; line: 1, column: 2]
```

The curious is if:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
   converters.add(httpMessageConverterConfig.stringHttpMessageConverter());
   converters.add(httpMessageConverterConfig.mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter());
   converters.add(httpMessageConverterConfig.mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
}
```

Again:

1. String
2. XML
3. Json

is changed to:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
   converters.add(httpMessageConverterConfig.stringHttpMessageConverter());
   converters.add(httpMessageConverterConfig.mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
   converters.add(httpMessageConverterConfig.mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter());

}
```

1. String
2. Json
3. XML

Now all work fine. Therefore the order of the list is crucial.

Why this behaviour? 
Or something else is missing?

**Requirement** declare the list without matter the order of the items and trusting in the HTTP headers.

Comment: Does controller endpoint for /persons have produces attribute ? if not present , better add produces="MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8"

Comment: Yes, it has the following `@GetMapping(produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})`